# Composite key where part of key is from superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism

I am having some object on the form.

```
abstract class AbstractSomething{
    int myMember;
    // getters and setters
}


class ConcreteClass extends AbstractSomething{
    int someOtherMember;
    String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Now I would like persist the `ConcreteClass`(in one database table) in my database where the unique key should be a composition of myMember and `someOtherMember` using hibernate annotation.
For what I can see composite keys would normally be created using `@Embedded` and `@EmbedderID` - but I cannot see how to do the trick when one of the keyparts is actually from a superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with an [`@IdClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html). Something like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class AbstractSomething {
    @Id
    int myMember;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ConcreteClass.Key.class)
class ConcreteClass extends AbstractSomething {
    public static class Key {
        int myMember;
        int someOtherMember;
        // constructor, equals, hashCode
    }

    @Id
    int someOtherMember;
}
```

This is a little clunky, but i believe it should work.

Comment: Not sure if I get it. How would hibernate know that those two ints should actually be mapped into the ConcreteClass.Key class?

Comment: The `@IdClass` annotation says that the key class should be used for this entity. The names of the fields in the key class are then matched against names of fields in the entity class - the key class is essentially a projection of a subset of the fields in the entity class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to declare abstract getter and setter for  myMember`in`AbstractSomething`

```
abstract class AbstractSomething{
    abstract int getMyMember();
    abstract void setMyMember(int i);        
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then declare

```
@Embeddable class SomethingId {
    String name;
    int myMember;
}
```

And your concrete class:

```
class ConcreteClass extends AbstractSomething{

    @EmbeddedId SomethingId somethingId ;

    int someOtherMember;

    @Override
    public int getMyMember(){
        return somethingId.myMember;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMyMember(int i){
        somethingId.myMember = i;
    }

   // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: That would be changing the structure around the problem. Not an option in my case.